# Order in jsonb_build_object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to keep the order of the fields in Postgre **jsonb_build_object**.

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'system', 'sss',
    'value', 'xxx');
```

result: `{"value": "xxx", "system": "sss"}`

I need: `{"system": "sss", "value": "xxx"}`

Comment: "I want to keep the order of the fields" why? Which JSON parser are you using where it makes a difference?

Comment: Weird service that receives JSON requires a certain order

Comment: I guess you could say "weird service that claims to accept JSON actually only accepts *its* idea of JSON". You are going to have to always keep this data in textual form (such as the `json` type rather than `jsonb`) and never deserialize it in an application, otherwise again the ordering could change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON doesn't have an order, and `jsonb` will reorder the attributes as it thinks fit. Use the data type `json` and `json_build_object()` if you need a certain order.